# Format Old Linux SD card on windows

Tags: linux, partitioning, raspberry-pi, sd-card, osmc

I have an 32 GB micro SD card (Class 10, samsung) which was used in the past for an OSMC box. However, the partition was never extended to the full 32GB so when I insert the drive in windows (the only host OS available to me for a while) It only registers as 280 MB. Any Idea on how to reformat this to 32GB so I can flash a new Linux image.

I still have the OSMC raspberry pi on hand if that is useful. I believe SSH might be turned on.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Open an admin command prompt. Typing steps -

```
Diskpart
list disk
select Disk 1  (or whatever number showed as your SD disk)
clean
create partition primary
select partition 1
format fs=fat32 quick
assign letter=R
exit
```

Comment: That gives a 280mb partition no?

Comment: It should give you the full amount of the drive capacity. The "clean" command should delete any partitioning. Not specifying a size when using "create partition primary" command means to use the whole drive.

Answer (score 0):

I think there are some partitions available on your SD card. So that it's not supporting on windows. Better you can break all the partitions and create a new.

You can use gparted to do that :)

Comment: How exactly would i use gparted on windows?

Comment: Oh my dear. If you are using windows then there is a awesome free tool named `partition-wizard`.
You may look at this,
https://www.partitionwizard.com/